# Proof that enriched hom is a V-functor

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Working in a category $\mathcal{C}$ enriched over a closed, symmetric, monoidal category $(\mathcal{V}, \times, *)$, with an object $U$ in $\mathcal{C}$ fixed, I'm trying to go through the details of a proof that the assignment $\mathcal{C}(-,U) : x \mapsto \mathcal{C}(x,U)$ defines a $\mathcal{V}$-functor from $\mathcal{C}^\text{op} \to \mathcal{V}$, but I'm stuck in showing that it preserves composition. According to section 1.6 in Kelly, it should follow easily from associativity.

This is as far as I've gotten: Using naturality of the adjunction $- \times \mathcal{C}(x,U) \dashv \mathcal{V}(\mathcal{C}(x,U),-)$, and defining $\mathcal{C}(-,U)_{xy} := \circ^\flat$, I know that since

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(x,y) \times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,x) @>{1 \times \circ}>> \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,y)\\ 
@V{\circ \times 1}VV @VV{\circ}V \\ \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(x,z) \times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,x) @>>{\circ}> \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,z)
\end{CD}$$

commutes, the square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(x,y)  @>{(1 \times \circ)^\flat}>> \mathcal{V}(\mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,x), \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,y))\\ 
@V{\circ}VV @VV{\circ_*}V \\ \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(x,z) @>>{\circ^\flat}> \mathcal{V}(\mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,x), \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,z))
\end{CD}$$

also commutes, but it isn't quite what I need - if the rightmost edge of the second diagram was instead

$$ \mathcal{V}(\mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,y), \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,z)) \times  \mathcal{V}(\mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,x), \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,y)) \xrightarrow{\qquad \circ \qquad}  \mathcal{V}(\mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,x), \mathcal{C}^\text{op}(U,z)),$$

then I'd be done. I don't see any obvious relationship between that map and the rightmost edge of the second diagram, so I worry that there's something simple about working with transposes of maps through adjunctions that I'm missing. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is a game of adjunctions. Since $\mathcal{C}(-, U) : \mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ is the same as $\mathcal{C}^{op}(U,-) : \mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$, we will work with the covariant functor $\mathcal{C}(U,-) : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\mathcal{V}$-category. We will denote the internal hom of $\mathcal{V}$ by $[-,-]$. Further, for all objects $a \in \mathcal{V}$, we shall denote the unit and counit of the adjunction $- \times a \dashv [a,-]$ by the same letters $d$ and $e$ respectively. Lastly, we denote the composition of the underlying category $\mathcal{V}_0$ of the monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$ by simple juxtaposition.

What you need is the commutativity of
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 \mathcal{C}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}(x,y)@>{\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times\text{ }\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y}}>> [\mathcal{C}(U,y), \mathcal{C}(U,z)] \times [\mathcal{C}(U,x), \mathcal{C}(U,y)] \\
@V{\circ}VV @V{\circ}VV\\
\mathcal{C}(x,z) @>{\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,z}}>> [\mathcal{C}(U,x), \mathcal{C}(U,z)]
\end{CD}

Applying to this (once for the (left arrow,bottom arrow) composite and once for the (top arrow, right arrow) composite), the naturality in $A$ of the adjunction bijection

$$\mathcal{V}(A \times \mathcal{C}(U,x), B) \cong \mathcal{V}(A, [\mathcal{C}(U,x), B])$$
yields the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 \left([\mathcal{C}(U,y),\mathcal{C}(U,z)] \times [\mathcal{C}(U,x), \mathcal{C}(U,y)]\right) \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) @>{e(1 \times e)a}>> \mathcal{C}(U,z)\\
 @A{\phantom{long}\left(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times\text{ }\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y}\right) \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)}}AA @V{1}VV \\
 (\mathcal{C}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}(x,y)) \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) @. \mathcal{C}(U,z)  \\
@V{\circ \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)}}VV @A{1}AA \\
\mathcal{C}(x,z) \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) @>{\circ}>> \mathcal{C}(U,z)
\end{CD}
Thus, it suffices to prove the commutativity of this diagram. We will infact show that
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 \left([\mathcal{C}(U,y),\mathcal{C}(U,z)] \times [\mathcal{C}(U,x), \mathcal{C}(U,y)]\right) \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) @>{e(1 \times e)a}>> \mathcal{C}(U,z)\\
 @A{\phantom{long}\left(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times\text{ }\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y}\right) \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)}}AA @V{1}VV \\
 (\mathcal{C}(y,z) \times \mathcal{C}(x,y)) \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) @>{\circ(1 \times \circ)a}>> \mathcal{C}(U,z)  \\
@V{\circ \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)}}VV @A{1}AA \\
\mathcal{C}(x,z) \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) @>{\circ}>> \mathcal{C}(U,z)
\end{CD}
is commutative. The bottom square is commutative since it is just **associativity of the composition in $\mathcal{C}$**. Thus, we just need to show that the top square commutes as well.

Now, observe that from the adjunctions $- \times \mathcal{C}(U,y) \dashv [\mathcal{C}(U,y), -]\text{ and }- \times \mathcal{C}(U,x) \dashv [\mathcal{C}(U,x), -]$,$$e(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,y)}) = \circ\quad\text{and}\quad e(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y} \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)}) = \circ\qquad\quad\text{(#)}\\$$

Thus, $e(1 \times e)a(\left(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times\text{ }\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y}\right) \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)})$

= $e(1 \times e)\left(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times (\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y} \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)})\right)a\quad\text{(using the naturality of the associator } a)$

= $e\left(1\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times e(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{x,y} \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,x)})\right)a\qquad\text{(interchange law between }\times\text{ and composition in }\mathcal{V}_0)$

= $e\left(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times \circ\right)a\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(using (#))}$

= $e\left(\mathcal{C}(U,-)_{y,z} \times 1_{\mathcal{C}(U,y)}\right)(1 \times o)a\qquad\qquad\text{ }\qquad\text{(interchange law between }\times\text{ and composition in }\mathcal{V}_0)$

= $\circ(1 \times \circ)a\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(using (#))}$

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation! The only thing I don't quite get is why the equalities hold in (#), could you say more about that?

Comment: The equalities follow from the formula for conjugates in an adjunction using the unit/counit natural transformation. Suppose you have an adjunction isomorphism $B(Fa , b) \cong A(a , Gb)$ with associated unit $d$ and counit $e$. Then, given an arrow $f : Fa \rightarrow b$, the conjugate $g : a \rightarrow Gb$ is given by $g = G(f) \circ d_a$ and likewise for the conjugate in the other direction.